# Was Migdal bavel a rocket ship?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach

I seem to remember hearing somewhile ago that the tower of bavel was a rocket. What is the source that migdal bavel was a "rocket"; or some thing that would fly up to the sky instead of the usual translation of a really tall building?